# app.callback function doesn't work, no error message (dash)

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a small Dash web app that works nicely, allowing the user to input data & upload data to generate a number of plots. I tried to add a button that would allow people to try out the software and view some sample plots without needing to enter or upload any data, but the `@app.callback` I added has broken the web app entirely.

You can test out the web app [here](https://fyp-web-app-harry.herokuapp.com/). This is the working version that doesn't contain the new feature. I can included a screenshot of what the figures look like here.

[image: sample figures]

Below is the code for the new `@app.callback` and button I added which not only doesn't work, but breaks the 'add row' button.

**Button**

```
row6 = html.Div([
          html.P('Just checking the software out?'),
          html.Button('Click here to generate a report with sample data',
                      id='sample_button',
                      n_clicks=0)],
          style={'text-align':'center', 'margin-top':80})
```

**@app.callback**

```
@app.callback(Output('splitter', 'children'),
              Input('sample_button', 'n_clicks'))
def sample_output(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks > 0:
        data = [[0,5,92,3,1,'03:00'],
                [1,10,148,37,1.1,'06:00'],
                [2,11,158,41,1.1,'09:00'],
                [3,12,167,44,1.3,'12:00'],
                [4,13,176,48,1.6,'15:00'],
                [5,14,180,51,1.9,'18:00'],
                [6,15,186,55,2.7,'21:00'],
                [7,16,189,57,3.8,'24:00'],
                [8,17,193,60,5.9,'27:00']]
        athlete_stats_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Stage', 'Velocity (km/h)', 'HR', 'VO2/Kg', 'Blood Lactate', 'Stage Finish Time'])

        pane2 = (html.Div([
            html.Div([
                dcc.Graph(figure=figFunc('HR', 'Blood Lactate'), style={'display':'inline-block'}),
                dcc.Graph(figure=figFunc('HR', 'Velocity (km/h)'), style={'display':'inline-block'}),
                ]),

            html.Div([
                dcc.Graph(figure=figFunc('HR', 'VO2/Kg'), style={'display':'inline-block'}),
                dcc.Graph(figure=figFunc('Blood Lactate', 'Velocity (km/h)'), style={'display':'inline-block'}),
                ]),

            dcc.Graph(figure=figFunc('VO2/Kg', 'Blood Lactate'))
            ], style={'overflow':'scroll', 'display':'inline-block'}))
        
        global pane1
        children = [pane1, pane2]

        return children
```

**App layout**

```
global pane1
pane1 = html.Div([
    row1,
    html.Br(),
    row2,
    html.Br(),
    row3,
    html.Br(),
    row4,
    html.Br(),
    row5,
    html.Br(),
    row6
    ])

pane2 = html.Div(
    table,
    )

app.layout = dash_split_pane.DashSplitPane(
    children=[pane1, pane2],
    id="splitter",
    split="vertical",
    size=500
    )
```

**Add Row Button**

Keep in mind this works perfectly except when I add the new feature.

```
row4 = html.Div(
        dbc.Row(
            html.Button('Add Row',
                        id='add_row',n_clicks=0),
            style={"text-align":"center"}
         )

    )
```

And the accompanying `@app.callback`

```
@app.callback(
Output('table-container_3', 'data'),
Output('bloodLactateId', 'value'),
Output('velocityId', 'value'),
Output('stageFinishTimeId', 'value'),
Input('add_row', 'n_clicks'),
State('table-container_3', 'data'),
State('table-container_3', 'columns'),
State('bloodLactateId', 'value'),
State('velocityId', 'value'),
State('stageFinishTimeId', 'value'))

def add_row(n_clicks, rows, columns, selectedBloodLactate, selectedVelocity,
            selectedStageFinishTime):

    if n_clicks > 0:
        rows.append({c['id']: r for c,r in zip(columns,
                                               [selectedBloodLactate,
                                                selectedVelocity,
                                                selectedStageFinishTime])})

    return rows, '', '', ''
```

You can view the full code in a GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/harryob2/temp-fyp-dash).

If you comment out the entire new `@app.callback` the code works again. However, if you comment out what's inside the @app.callback, it still doesn't work.

I'm at a loss here. Any help, even meek suggestions, will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Turn on debug mode. You have two dash errors.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Mack Raymond for pointing out that I had debug mode turned off, and when turned on I get the following error;

> In the callback for output(s): 
> splitter.children Output 0 
> (splitter.children) is already in use. Any given output can only have 
> one callback that sets it. To resolve this situation, try combining 
> these into one callback function, distinguishing the trigger by using 
> `dash.callback_context` if necessary.

I needed to merge the 2 callbacks into 1. Below is how I did it.

```
@app.callback(Output('splitter', 'children'), # change layout to output-plot
              Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
              Input('sample_button', 'n_clicks'),
              State('upload-data', 'filename'),
              State('table-container_3', 'data'), prevent_initial_call=True)
def update_plot(HR_df, n_clicks, filename, GUI_df):
    global pane1
    global athlete_stats_df
    if n_clicks > 0:
        data = [[1,10,148,37,1.1,'06:00'],
                [2,11,158,41,1.1,'09:00'],
                [3,12,167,44,1.3,'12:00'],
                [4,13,176,48,1.6,'15:00'],
                [5,14,180,51,1.9,'18:00'],
                [6,15,186,55,2.7,'21:00'],
                [7,16,189,57,3.8,'24:00'],
                [8,17,193,60,5.9,'27:00']]
        athlete_stats_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Stage', 'Velocity (km/h)', 'HR', 'VO2/Kg', 'Blood Lactate', 'Stage Finish Time'])
        
        pane2 = (html.Div([
            html.Div([
                dcc.Graph(figure=figFunc('HR', 'Blood Lactate'), style={'display':'inline-block', 'align-items':'baseline'}),
                dcc.Graph(figure=figFunc('HR', 'Velocity (km/h)'), style={'display':'inline-block'}),
                ]),

            html.Div([
                dcc.Graph(figure=figFunc('HR', 'VO2/Kg'), style={'display':'inline-block'}),
                dcc.Graph(figure=figFunc('Blood Lactate', 'Velocity (km/h)'), style={'display':'inline-block'}),
                ]),

            dcc.Graph(figure=figFunc('VO2/Kg', 'Blood Lactate'))
            ], style={'height':'100%','overflow-y':'auto'}))
        
        children = [pane1, pane2]

        return children
    
    elif filename is not None:
        pane2 = parse_contents_plot(HR_df, filename, GUI_df)
        children = [pane1, pane2]

        return children
```